# How many Observations in SAS Sample Data Output

Tags: database, sas, output

I have this sample SAS output and need to find out how many observations and compute the t-statistic for Beta1. Can anyone help me get started on how to go about doing this?

[Sample SAS Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV3La.png)

Comment: This isn't a SAS question, its a stats question and should be on cross validated. Its also easily answered by an entry level stats text book on ANOVA. How does DF relate to number of obs and how does a T-test relate to F-test?

Comment: EDIT: the t-stat is present in the table, what would you calculate? What's your hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of obs in a dataset you can run this code.

```
data _null_;
put nobs=;
stop;
set sashelp.class nobs=nobs;
run;
```

A proc reg will give you all the summary statistics you need, namely, t-value, beta1 and beta null, which are your intercepts of your regression equation.
Here is a simple easy to follow example `http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect003.htm`